# Using a while loop to add and subtract a current location

Tags: python, loops, variables, while-loop

```
def main():
    global currentX,currentY
    currentX = 0
    currentY = 0
    currentlocation = currentX,currentY
    print("Starting Location is", currentX,currentY)
    print()

    #Main menu dialouge

    print("Please select direction:")
    print("1, North;")
    print("2, East;")
    print("3, South;")
    print("4, West;")
    print("5, End this program")

    #Loop = to 1 so while loop will go on indefitly until option 5 is pressed.
    loop = 1
    #try: handles all errors along with except:
    try:
        while loop == 1:
            direction = input("--> ")
            print()
            direction = int(direction)
            if direction == 1:
                moveN = currentY + 1
                print("Moved North.",currentlocation)

            elif direction == 2:
                currentX + 1
                print("Moved East.",currentlocation)

            elif direction == 3:
                currentY - 1
                print("Moved South.",currentlocation)

            elif direction == 4:
                currentX - 1
                print("Moved West.",currentlocation)

            elif direction == 5:
                loop = 0
                print("Final location is", currentlocation)

            else:
                    print("ERROR:", choice, "is an invalid input.\n"
                          "Enter a number from 1 to 5.")
    except: ValueError
    print("Please enter a whole number between 1-5")

main()
```

I can't figure out why the loop doesn't add to the currentlocation. 
I get an output like 
Starting Location is 0 0

```
Please select direction:
1, North;
2, East;
3, South;
4, West;
5, End this program
--> 3
Moved South. (0, 0)
--> 4
Moved West. (0, 0)
```

Comment: Read some of: [Understanding Python variables and Memory Management](http://foobarnbaz.com/2012/07/08/understanding-python-variables/).

Answer (score 2):

You aren't actually changing currentX and currentY, you're merely evaluating the values you want them to have.  To change them, you need to assign to them:

```
currentX = currentX + 1
```

or, more concisely:

```
currentX += 1
```

Your direction 1 case also looks off.  For some reason you're assigning to `moveN`.  I have no idea what that's supposed to do.

Edit:  You also need to update `currentlocation` to reflect the changes in position.

Comment: This still won't fix OPs issue. They want `currentlocation` to update, but they're not ever touching it.

Comment: You should also address `currentlocation` not updating as a result of changing `currentX` or `currentY`.  This answer doesn't completely solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I added that.  There were multiple problems and I just mentioned the first ones that I noticed.

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
currentlocation = currentX,currentY
```

You're not actually creating a tuple with references to currentX and currentY, you're creating a tuple with whatever *values* were in currentX and currentY at the time it was declared.  So every time you change those, it's not updated.

One way to fix this is turn currentlocation into a function.

```
def currentlocation():
    return currentX,currentY
```

Then, instead of

```
print(currentlocation)
```

Just put

```
print(currentlocation())
```